# Show previews of several images on one page with PHP and Jquery of javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a html-page where the user should upload several pictures for different screen resolutions. I need a separate file selection and preview for each picture, so I can store the pictures in the right places on upload. With one multiselect it is nearly imposible to figure out which picture belongs to which type.

Fileselections are no problem, but as I am not a JavaScript of Jquery programmer, getting a preview is no problem, but all preview images appear in the first picture.

This code will display a page with placeholders and file-selections:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Upload Image using form</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="imageupload.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mainform">
        <h2>Upload multiple images using forms</h2>
            <table>
            <?php
                echo '<tr><td><h3>Picture</h3></td></tr>';
                echo '<tr><td>LowRes</td><td>';
                loadPreview("div_PreviewPicLowRes",107, 71);
                echo '</td></tr><tr><td>Medium</td><td>';
                loadPreview("div_previewPicMedium",236, 157);
                echo '</td></tr><tr><td>HD</td><td>';
                loadPreview("div_previewPichd",320, 213);
                echo '</td></tr><tr><td>UltraHD</td><td>';
                loadPreview("div_previewPic4k",426, 284);
                echo '</td></tr>';
            ?>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>


<?php
    function loadPreview($id = 'div', $x=420, $y=300 ) {
        echo '
        <div id="div'.$id.'">
            <div id="preview'.$id.'">
                <img id="previewimg" src=""  width="'.$x.'px" height="'.$y.'px">    
            </div>
            <div id="formdiv'.$id.'">
                <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form'.$id.'" method="post" name="form'.$id.'">
                    <div id="upload'.$id.'">
                        <input type="file" name="file'.$id.'" accept="image/*">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>';
    }
?>
```

This javascript will display a preview:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Function for Preview Image.
    $(function() {
        $(":file").change(function() {
            if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
                reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
            }
        });
    });

    function imageIsLoaded(e) {
        $('#message').css("display", "none");
        $('#preview').css("display", "block");
        $('#previewimg').attr('src', e.target.result);
    };
});
```

Now All images appear in the first placeholder, but I need show them in the same line as the file-selector. I know the Jquery part is responsible for displaying the image and it is coded to show the image in previewimg, but I can't figure out to use other div-id's.

Can somebody please help me out?

Comment: It seems you have several HTML `img` tags with the same ID (`<img id="previewimg"`)

Answer (score 0):

The way you are set up at the moment, you can add one file and the form submits this is then added to the dom via JS.

However since the form submits and refreshes the page each time you will only ever have $_FILES info in PHP to save to the DB for the last image submitted.

The way I'd do this is like so:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_FILES['lowres']) && !empty($_FILES['lowres'])){
    $lowres_filename = $_FILES['lowres']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['lowres']['tmp_name'], "images/$lowres_filename");
    $_SESSION['lowres'] = $lowres_filename;
}
if(isset($_FILES['medium']) && !empty($_FILES['medium'])){
    $medium_filename = $_FILES['medium']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['medium']['tmp_name'], "images/$medium_filename");
    $_SESSION['medium'] = $medium_filename;
}
if(isset($_FILES['hd']) && !empty($_FILES['hd'])){
    $hd_filename = $_FILES['hd']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['hd']['tmp_name'], "images/$hd_filename");
    $_SESSION['hd'] = $hd_filename;
}
if(isset($_FILES['uhd']) && !empty($_FILES['uhd'])){
    $uhd_filename = $_FILES['uhd']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['uhd']['tmp_name'], "images/$uhd_filename");
    $_SESSION['uhd'] = $uhd_filename;
}
?>

<table>
<tr>
    <td>LowRes</td>
    <td><?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['lowres']) && !empty($_SESSION['lowres'])){
        echo '<img id="lowres" src="images/'.$_SESSION['lowres'].'">';
    }else{
        echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST"><input type="file" name="lowres" onchange="this.form.submit();"></form>';
    }
    ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Medium</td>
    <td><?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['medium']) && !empty($_SESSION['medium'])){
        echo '<img id="medium" src="images/'.$_SESSION['medium'].'">';
    }else{
        echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST"><input type="file" name="medium" onchange="this.form.submit();"></form>';
    }
    ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>HD</td>
    <td><?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['hd']) && !empty($_SESSION['hd'])){
        echo '<img id="hd" src="images/'.$_SESSION['hd'].'">';
    }else{
        echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST"><input type="file" name="hd" onchange="this.form.submit();"></form>';
    }
    ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>UltraHD</td>
    <td><?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['uhd']) && !empty($_SESSION['uhd'])){
        echo '<img id="uhd" src="images/'.$_SESSION['uhd'].'">';
    }else{
        echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST"><input type="file" name="uhd" onchange="this.form.submit();"></form>';
    }
    ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your solution works, but after each upload the page is refreshed. My code is only a part on the page and that takes way to long. There is a lot more on the page and reloading will take several seconds. That's why I need to write the images directly to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I see with your example would be submitting 4 forms and only being able to process one image at a time unless you have some way of handling all of the forms submitting together.

You can try it this way instead:

Test1.php:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>LowRes</td>
    <td id="low_cell"><input type="file" name="low" id="low" onchange="get_images('low');"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Medium</td>
    <td id="med_cell"><input type="file" name="med" id="med" onchange="get_images('med');"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>HD</td>
    <td id="hd_cell"><input type="file" name="hd" id="hd" onchange="get_images('hd');"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>UltraHD</td>
    <td id="uhd_cell"><input type="file" name="uhd" id="uhd" onchange="get_images('uhd');"></td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
function get_images(res){
    var form_data = new FormData();
    var file = document.getElementById(res).files[0];
    form_data.append("file", file);
    form_data.append("res", res);
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            var image = document.createElement("img");
            image.setAttribute("src", "images/"+this.responseText);
            document.getElementById(res+'_cell').prepend(image);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "test2.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send(form_data);
}
</script>
```

test2.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['res'])){
    $res = $_POST['res'];
}

if(isset($_FILES['file']) && !empty($_FILES['file'])){
    $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "images/".$file);
    $_SESSION[$res] = $file;
    echo $file;
}
?>
```